# Pivot SQL Server data, concatenate multiple column data into computed column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

FYI: I'm using `SQL Server`.

I have a table where I query for one column but it may contain multiple records:

```
SELECT CodeNumber
FROM Books
WHERE Type='Children'

CodeNumer
---------
A
B
C
D
E
```

I want to `PIVOT` the table and concatenate the column data into a computed column such that it looks like this:

```
ComputedColumn
--------------
A; B; C; D; E;
```

I'm open to using something else other than pivot in the query. I'd prefer not to write a stored procedure which will perform this action.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a `PIVOT` because you aren't turning those values into columns, since you want to concatenate them into a single row the duplicate should offer a variety of ways to solve it.

Comment: No problem. I don't know what the protocol is, as far as if this question should be deleted, but I found my answer from the duplicate: `SELECT STUFF( ( SELECT ' ' + CodeNumber + ';' FROM Books WHERE Type='Children' FOR XML PATH( '' ) ), 1, 1, '')`. Thank you so much for pointing out that question! I thought `PIVOT` was the answer but, you're right, I'm not turning values into columns.